# Name of customers who are of legal age (18 years) Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question about how to return only customers over 18 years old.
I'm just getting back from the customers

```
SELECT 
    custname,
    (2021 - part_date ('year', custdatebirth)) AS age
FROM 
    customers;
```

Comment: Why not use a `WHERE` clause for that? Can you share more details about your problem?

Comment: Can you provide sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter the rows, use a `where` clause.  If you want to filter by age, you can use date comparisons:

```
where custdatebirth < current_date - interval '18 year'
```

Note that phrasing the condition this way makes it friendlier to indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This solution of this could be as follow

```
SELECT 
    custname,
    custdatebirth
FROM 
    customers
WHERE 
   EXTRACT(YEAR, custdatebirth) <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)-18;
```